# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1) in Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, integer

I am trying to convert string to int but it is throwing an exception "Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)"

```
String aa = "627a32b69018c4b90f77af19";
int.parse(aa);
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: try to just `print(aa);`

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil it is throwing exception on int.parse code.

Comment: what do you exact print?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I want to print exactly the same but in int format.

Comment: What do you expect? The string you have is not an integer, especially the characters of the alphabet that your string contains.

Comment: @nvoigt So there is no way?

Comment: You should really clarify what the expected behavior is that you are trying to achieve. What comes into this method, is it hexadecimal, decimal, should it return null as it is no integer etc etc.

Comment: What output do you expect? No, parsing it as a normal integer, there is no way. But maybe you don't want that. It's just that we cannot read your mind, what you actually expect the output to be, so we cannot really tell you what to do.

Comment: @MohammedNabil not print above string to int format

Comment: @nvoigt i want same output but in integer format

Comment: Again, can you please just post the output you expect for the code you gave? Not a description, the actual output. What do you *want* this to give you. "7"? "42"? What integer do you *want* to come out of this?

Comment: @nvoigt expected output after converting to integer `627a32b69018c4b90f77af19`

Comment: That is already your input. If you need that as output, you don't need to convert at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The passed string is not a number as it contains non-digit characters like `a` or `f`.

It seems that you like to parse the input string as a hexadecimal string, in that case provide a radix (number base) value in your code.

The following snipped yields the output of `3.047725939849963e+28`.

```
void main() {
  String aa = "627a32b69018c4b90f77af19";
  int? test = int.parse(aa, radix: 16);
  
  print("$test");
}
```

However, your number seems to be very large (10^28). There the result exceeds the range of an `int`, which is 64 bit at most, 32 bit for JavaScript. ([more](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-core/int-class.html#:%7E:text=The%20available%20integer%20values%20include,Dart%20code%20compiled%20to%20JavaScript.))

In these cases it is best to  use [BigInt](https://api.dart.dev/be/176281/dart-core/BigInt-class.html), which supports arbitrarily large integer numbers.

Comment: Now getting new exception error "Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Positive input exceeds the limit of integer"

Comment: I edited my answer with a working code snipped. In your case the value grew too large for an int to handle. In that case use https://api.dart.dev/be/176281/dart-core/BigInt-class.html for large numbers. Consider accepting my answer if it helped you.